# Calculate complex eigenvector

Tags: matrices, complex-numbers, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Hi i have problem i hope that someone can make this for me more clear:
So i have matrix $A = \begin{bmatrix} -2 & 1 \\ -2 & 0 \\ \end{bmatrix}$

I have to calculate eigenvector as matrix $P$ from it. So form matrix i have:
$ \lambda^2 + 2 \lambda + 2 $ so there will be complex eigenvalues

$\lambda_{1} = -1 - i$

$\lambda_{2} = -1 + i$

$\begin{bmatrix} -1 - i & 1 \\ -2 & 1 - i\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}$

so from this i have something like this

$y = x + xi \\
-2x + 2x = 0$

Now here is problem, how calculate eigenvector form this? What matrix will P look like?

I check solution in my book and there is something like this:

$P = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1\end{bmatrix}$

And i have no idea how get matrix P from those equation, can somebody help? I would be very grateful.

EDIT:: What if i have eigenvector like this:

$y = (1 - 2i)x $ for  $ \lambda_{1} = -1 -i$

$y = (1 + 2i)x$ for $\lambda_{2} = -1 + 1$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your eigenvalue $\lambda_2=-1+i$:

$$\begin{bmatrix} -1 - i & 1 \\ -2 & 1 - i\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}$$

This gives you
$$y=(1+i)x$$
So the eigenvector corresponding to $\lambda_2$ is
$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1+i\end{bmatrix} $$

Repeating for $\lambda_1$, you will get the eigenvector
$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1-i\end{bmatrix} $$

Now looking at the real parts and imaginary parts of the two eigenvectors. The first component is $1$, which gives you $1,0$ for the first row of $P$. The second component has real part $1$, imaginary part $1$, (since they are complex conjugate of each other) which give you $1,1$ for the second row of $P$.

Comment: Thx,but i dont understand this part " The first component is $1$, which gives you $1,0$ for the first row of $P$" Is there some rule or formula to build matrix P when are complex? $ P = \begin{bmatrix} Re & Im \\ Re & Im \end{bmatrix}$ Why real parts equal 1 and 1 gives me 1 and 0?

Comment: @ $1$ as a complex number has real part $1$ and imaginary part $0$. It is $1+0\cdot i$. And yes, $P$ is built like that.

Comment: Yes but is there not imaginary equal  i and -i?

Comment: @Hadson: If you are talking about $1+i$ and $1-i$, since they are conjugate to each other (and it will always be the case), we only take the positive value. For example, if the vectors are \begin{bmatrix} 1+2i \\ 3+4i\end{bmatrix} and \begin{bmatrix} 1-2i \\ 3-4i\end{bmatrix}, then we get $P=\begin{bmatrix} 1 &2 \\ 3&4\end{bmatrix}$ .

Comment: So i the second case(edited question) there will be 
$P = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 2 \end{bmatrix}$ Am i right?

Comment: @Hadson: Correct.

Comment: Okey :D you helped a lot :D thank you very much :)

Comment: @Hadson: You are welcome :)